# Casting in swift

Tags: swift

So my swift skills arent great... I want to try and retrieve an audio track description for a video and have come up with this method. If anything fails the method should return null

```
   func getAudioTrackDescription(path: String) -> AudioStreamBasicDescription? {
        let asset = getAssetFromPath(path: path)
        guard let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first else {      
            return nil
        }
        
        
        guard let audioDesc = track.formatDescriptions.first else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // let casted = audioDesc as! CMAudioFormatDescription

        // THE SDF IS JUST AN EXAMPLE THAT CAUSES IT TO FAIL 
        // I ACTUALLY WANT TO USE THE COMMENTED LINE ABOVE
        if let casted = ("Sdf" as! CMAudioFormatDescription) {
            let basic = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(casted)
            guard let pointee = basic?.pointee else {
                return nil
            }
            return pointee
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

I am really struggling to understand how the casting works in swift...
The track.formatDescriptions list holds type Any which means it could crash if the type is not what i expect it to be (CMAudioFormatDescription)

For example I have changed the if audioDesc to be the string "Sdf" and the code crashes.

I want to be able to check if audioDesc can be casted to CMAudioFormatDescription and if cant i want to return nil.

I tried using as? and this always gives me this error

```
Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'CMAudioFormatDescription' (aka 'CMFormatDescription') will always succeed
```

Can someone help?

---------------------- EDIT

is below a safe approach?

```
    func getVideoAudioChannelCount(path: String) -> Int {
        guard let audioFile = getAudioInformation(path: path) else {
               return DEFAULT_AUDIO_CHANNEL
        }
        return Int(audioFile.channelCount)
    }
    
    
    func getAudioInformation(path: String) -> AVAudioFormat? {
        var returnVar: AVAudioFormat?;
        do {
            returnVar = try AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)).fileFormat
        } catch _ {
            returnVar = nil
        }
        return returnVar
    }
```

Comment: just try to take a look at `CMAudioFormatDescription.init(...)` and find needed initializer. `String` and `CMAudioFormatDescription` are not the same, they are absolutely different types and can't be force casted to each other.

Comment: I know they cannot be casted and it should fail but how do i handle this? The actual line i want to use is commented l"et casted = audioDesc as! CMAudioFormatDescription" and the sdf string was just an example. Could you please provide me some example code that will cast it correctly if if it fails return nil

Comment: Do you really need `AudioStreamBasicDescription` in the first place? With `AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)).fileFormat` you would get https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioformat a convenient wrapper for `AudioStreamBasicDescription`

Comment: @Kamil.S I have edited my question to use AVAudioFile as you have suggested, Could you tell me if what I have done is safe from exceptions

Comment: Unrelated: but get rid of `returnVar`. Just `return try? AVAudioFile...`. Also, don't use strings as paths. Use URLs, like all of Apple's APIs do. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Dates%20aren't%20Strings.md

Comment: Yes, it is safe, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I can recall many APIs that uses a string as a path, like `String.init(contentsOfFile:)`...

Comment: @Sweeper That's a legacy API, imported from `NSString`. A whole bunch of "path" related APIs are deprecated, although not that one. IMO it's a completely misplaced responsibility for a string to know how to load itself from a file

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for the help. :) I'm not really sure how to create my URL without the string path... is it ok to leave it as it is?

Comment: @ebg11 You can still create the URL with a string. Alexander is just saying that `getVideoAudioChannelCount` should accept a `URL` as parameter instead of a `String`. The caller can then create the URL with a string, or in whatever way they want.

Comment: @Sweeper Oh ok that makes sense. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack/1386694-formatdescriptions), the array will always contain `CMFormatDescription` (aka `CMAudioFormatDescription`), so you can safely cast with `as!`.

> The array contains CMFormatDescriptions (see CMFormatDescription), each of which indicates the format of media samples referenced by the track.

You get the error that conditional casts always succeed because `CMAudioFormatDescription` is a Core Foundation type (it conforms to `_CFObject`). For more info, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/11171).

Edit:

> is below a safe approach?

Yes, if by "safe" you mean it won't crash. You can simplify the code if you use `try?`:

```
func getAudioInformation(path: String) -> AVAudioFormat? {
    try? AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)).fileFormat
}
```